# Is there a way to avoid CORDIC algorithm to enter negative results?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am writing CORDIC algorithm into AVR microcontroller using assembly language, using 20 bits in the calculation, both the input angle and the output sin() and cos() is multiplied by 2^20.  It works very nice, fast (less than 70µs for the calculation, using 16MHz clock), so it can calculates more than 14285 angles per second.

I needed to circumvent a negative number problem, in the "angle-atan(2^n)", where atan(2^n) is a table with 21 elements of 3 bytes, WHEN the input angle is lower than 4.3988... degrees.

I understand the problem.
The series of angles atan(1/(2^n)), where n goes from 0 to 20, is;
45,
26.5650512,
14.0362435,
7.1250164,
3.5763344,
1.7899106... and so on.

If the input angle is, for example 4.39, the tracking angle will start with 0, as it is less than 4.39, the routine will add angle 45 (r:45), result is higher than 4,
subtract 26.5650512 (r:18.4349488), still higher,
subtract 14.0362435 (r:4.3987054), still higher,
subtract 7.1250163 (**r:-2.7263110**)... here the negative angle.

It creates confusion with the unsigned integers calculation. Of course I was able to check if negative (carry) numbers appears and fix it in the unsigned multi-byte operation. The routine increase in size because of that, and becomes less efficient.  This only happens with angles smaller than 4.398 and higher than 85.602 degrees.  All the angles within this range never creates negative results.

The original CORDIC calculation requires the use of signed numbers, I guess just because of this.
It is interesting, because if you think of 17 degrees at input, when subtracting 14.036, the result is 4.398, smaller than 13, so the next is adding 7.125, and so on, the result never goes negative.  For some math issues, the result goes negative only when the input is smaller than 4.3988.  In the routine, angle*2^20, so it is smaller than 4612476.

That is curious, since CORDIC updates (rotates) the resulting tracking angle, adding (if smaller) or subtracting (if higher) the atan(1/2^n), just to approximate more and more to the desired angle, and it makes sense to think it will never goes into negative tracking angle, but it does.

Any comments?  I am not a math person, so just excuse me.

Comment: The reason it can go negative is because the sum of the angles after the initial angle of 45 degrees is greater than 45 degrees. You could work around it by adding a check to see if adding/substracting will cause you to go negative and then skip that iteration, or perhaps work in steps of $45 \cdot 2^{-i}$ degrees (this will guarantee you don't overflow, but it might be a less accurate approximation).

Comment: Another option might be to for angles $\theta$ larger than $85.602$ or lower than $4.3988$ degrees to instead consider $\theta - 45^\circ$ and $\theta + 45^\circ$ respectively, and then at the and multiply by $R_{45}$ or $R_{-45}$ respectively, where $R_i$ is the rotation matrix by $i$ degrees.

Comment: I was able to bypass this problem adding 5 degrees to the floor tracking angle (usually starts with zero), and also adding 5 degrees for the desired angle to obtain sin().  This does not change anything in the calculation, the X (cos) and Y (sin) still exactly the same during the interactions, but the tracking angle never goes negative.  Now I can run angles as low as 0.01° or 89.99°, using plain unsigned integers for the angles.  Thank you for the thought.

Comment: Included extra MSB byte COS/SIN registers, going negative on the 4th iteration, the assembly makes them 0xFFNNNN). Add or sub the "pseudo-negative" value works correctly,  from 0.0001~89.999°.  Results are in 20 bits resolution with 18 bits precision. All integers and unsigned, except for that trick.   It was good learning CORDIC, mostly about the no scaling relationship between the angles and the Gain value that started Cosine.  Used 20 bits for the Gain and only 12 for the angle.  Angle tracking decides add/sub of the Cos/Sin, more bits on the Gain, better resolution of the result.

Comment: Why not just use signed values? 20 bits is 2.5 bytes. As you usually will operate on bytes anyway, just go 3-bytes signed values. Addition of `signed` is not more expensive than `unsigned` addition, same for subtraction and comparison. Also you have enough headroom bit-wise to increase the data range to cover negative values.  The only thing that needs a bit of attention (which will turn out to be handfull of additional instructions) is `signed` fractioal multiplicaton.